# Dealing with interface data using mapstructure

Tags: go, hashicorp-vault

I am getting data from the Hashicorp Vault API, and struggling to manipulate it because I have a hazy understanding of interfaces still :(

I am getting a TLS cert response from the PKI backend. Using go-dumper, it outputs this:

```
(0xc4203880c0) &Secret {
  RequestID: "271c63ef-d7b6-a084-18a0-966dd6989f03",
  LeaseID: "",
  LeaseDuration: 0 (int),
  Renewable: false,
  Data: map[string]interface {} {
    "serial_number": interface() ,
    "ca_chain": interface() ,
    "certificate": interface() ,
    "issuing_ca": interface() ,
    "private_key": interface() ,
    "private_key_type": interface()
  },
  Warnings: nil ([]string),
  Auth: nil (*api.SecretAuth),
  WrapInfo: nil (*api.SecretWrapInfo)
}
```

What I'd like to do is print the "certficate" field using `fmt`. So I did this:

Created a struct:

```
type TLSCredentialResp struct {
  IssuingCA  string `mapstructure:"issuing_ca"`
  PrivateKey string `mapstructure:"private_key"`
  CAChain    string `mapstructure:"ca_chain"`
  Cert       string `mapstructure:"certificate"`
}
```

and then used mapstructure to decode into it:

```
var response TLSCredentialResp
if err := mapstructure.Decode(docker.Data, &response); err != nil {
  log.Fatal("Error parsing vault's credential response: ", err)
}

fmt.Printf("Private Key: %s", response.PrivateKey)
```

However, when I try this, I get the following:

```
Error parsing vault's credential response: 1 error(s) decoding:
* 'ca_chain' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'
exit status 1
```

Now it's fairly clear to me I've gotten this wrong, as I'm trying to Decode an interface into a string. What isn't clear to me is *how* I deal with `interface()` as a type? Simply put, how can I get the plain text cert value out of that?

Comment: Did you mess with the output of go-dumper? It's showing `interface()` as a type but that's not a thing. `interface{}` is a type. Also your error indicates that ca-chain is a `[]interface{}` (slice of empty interface). The first thing to do is figure out what the underlying types are ([`fmt.Printf("%T")` can be helpful](https://play.golang.org/p/Z3NNC0B0U0)) and then go from there.

Comment: Nope, never seen it before with, but it's definitely `interface()`

Answer (score -1):

So I'm an idiot, this was way easier than I expected.

I don't need to use mapstructure it seems, I can just do this:

```
fmt.Printf("Private Key: %s", docker.Data["private_key"])
fmt.Printf("Cert: %s", docker.Data["certificate"])
```

Although I don't know why..